# Why is AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment failing randomly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-pipeline

I have setup AWS Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environment (Load Balanced) and random deployment failure issue. Many times, deployment works well. Sometimes it fails, here's what I found:

When I have multiple instances, deployment fails with error in EB events log `Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-*******'. Aborting the operation.`

I downloaded bundle log for particular instance and checked `eb-engine.log`, it shows sqsd starting failed. Other instances has no such issue.

eb-engine.log

```
2022/xx/xx xx:xx:xx.590911 [INFO] Executing instruction: configureSqsd
2022/xx/xx xx:xx:xx.595059 [INFO] get sqsd conf from cfn metadata and write into sqsd conf file ...
2022/xx/xx xx:xx:xx.596414 [INFO] Executing instruction: startSqsd
2022/xx/xx xx:xx:xx.596442 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf sqsd.service
2022/xx/xx xx:xx:xx.658752 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active sqsd.service
2022/xx/xx xx:xx:xx.697070 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start sqsd.service
2022/xx/xx xx:xx:xx.566439 [INFO] Job for sqsd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status sqsd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

2022/xx/xx xx:xx:xx.566462 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [startSqsd]. Stop running the command. Error: startProcess Failure: starting process "sqsd" failed: Command /bin/sh -c systemctl start sqsd.service failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Job for sqsd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status sqsd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: So what is the output of `systemctl status sqsd.service" and "journalctl -xe`?

Comment: those servers on private VPC without public IP. So running those command is not possible.

Comment: Sure it is. You can login there through a bastion host or use web ssh clients avaiabile in AWS console.

Comment: It even doesn't have Key pair set. Not sure if bastion host works without key.

Comment: Then use web clients. They do not require key pairs.

Comment: web ssh clients needs public IP

Comment: session manager does not require public ip.

Comment: "SSM Agent isn't installed on the instance".

Comment: Well, then that's it. You can't check error messages, so its unlikely to find the cause of the issue and fix it.

Comment: well.. again whole point. Those EBs are deployed by EB itself.., no custom install, no customization as such. some are good and why not.

Comment: Its not EB fault, that you have no access to it. You sadly misconfigured your entire EB-based architecture. By default session manager is always installed. So I don't know what did you do that you have your EB without it. I would suggest going back and verifying your configurations.

Comment: not buying last comment. EB provision 3 instances. How come 2 is good and 1 is problem. any way thank you.